# Sort a Dictionary by Its Value in Human Sort Order

Tags: c#

I want to sort a dictionary on based on its values and get a result dictionary

```
Dictionary<String, Int32> outputDictionary = new Dictionary<String, Int32>();
outputDictionary.Add("MyFirstValue", 1);
outputDictionary.Add("MySecondValue",2);
outputDictionary.Add("MyThirdValue", 10);
outputDictionary.Add("MyFourthValue", 20);
outputDictionary.Add("MyFifthValue", 5);
```

I used 3 methods to sort it by value

Method  1:

```
outputDictionary = outputDictionary.OrderBy(key => key.Value).ToDictionary(pair =>   pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

Method 2:

```
  foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> item in outputDictionary.OrderBy(key => key.Value))
 {
   // do something with item.Key and item.Value
 }
```

Method 3:

```
 outputDictionary = (from entry in outputDictionary orderby entry.Value ascending   select entry).ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

but no matter what Method I choose, I get result as

```
 MyFirstValue, 1
 MyThirdValue, 10
 MySecondValue, 2
 MyFourthValue, 20
 MyFifthValue, 5
```

Where as I want

```
  MyFirstValue, 1
  MySecondValue, 2
  MyFifthValue, 5
  MyThirdValue, 10
  MyFourthValue, 20
```

Comment: ??? What's the order you're wanting ? Not alphabetical, not numeric, but you want the code to understand that "Third" comes before "Fourth" ???

Comment: @Bartude, I want to sort it by value, where 2 comes before 10.

Comment: @Pankaj But 5 comes after 20?

Comment: ok so you may want to update your question cause in it 10 and 20 come before 5...

Comment: @Matthew, Yes, Sorry I want 5 to come before 10, Just edited that part. in question :(

Comment: @DoctorJOnes, You are right, I want 55 to come before 6.

Comment: If you use the int as the key instead you can use a `SortedDictionary`

Comment: (To be used in conjunction with the answers below) See here for an `IComparer<>` which does natural sort order: http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> myList = aDictionary.ToList();

myList.Sort(
    delegate(KeyValuePair<string, string> firstPair,
    KeyValuePair<string, string> nextPair)
    {
        return firstPair.Value.CompareTo(nextPair.Value);
    }
);
```

Comment: In the end I used this List<KeyValuePair<String, Int32>> and totally avoided Dictionary.

Answer (score 10):

Dictionaries are, by definition, not sortable. In an abstract sense, there are no guarantees whatsoever about the order elements are retrieved. There is code that may fetch the items in an ordered manner - I'm not so fluent in Linq but I think your code does that - but if you're going to use that data a lot, this is less efficient than having an already sorted structure available to iterate on. I recommend using some other type or set of types, like a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`.

You could also make either element of the `KeyValuePair` an integer (i.e.: `KeyValuePair<string, int>`), since that's what you want to sort by. String comparisons are alphabetical. And alphabetically, 20 does come before 5.

**edit:** [Magnus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/468973/magnus) suggested the [SortedDictionary class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Pankaj you can try this,instead of "MyFirstValue" i took the liberty of changing
to "1º value" and added in unsorted order,the output was ordered

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Dictionary<String, Int32> outputDictionary = new Dictionary<String, Int32>();
            outputDictionary.Add("3º value", 1);
            outputDictionary.Add("2º value", 2);
            outputDictionary.Add("1º value", 10);
            outputDictionary.Add("5º value", 20);
            outputDictionary.Add("4º value", 5);
            outputDictionary.Add("14º value", 8);
            outputDictionary.Add("10º value", 22);

            IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,int>> NewOrder = outputDictionary.OrderBy(k => int.Parse(Regex.Match(k.Key, @"\d+").Value));

            foreach (var item in NewOrder)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Key + " " + item.Value.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: How would this handle `"10º value"`?

Comment: hi  user7116 i just edited my answer in order of your comment,try it out.